# setting snmp extensions in snmpd.conf

Tags: snmp

On our servers ( debian, centos and ubuntu ) we set in snmpd.conf

```
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.1 distro "/bin/cat /etc/debian_version"
```

This way a centralized monitor ( Observium ) read the OS distro. Fine.

I read http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html
but ...

The OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.1 is a de-facto "standard" ?

Why python doesn't work ?

```
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.2 purpose "/usr/bin/python /root/snmp_helper.py --product"
```

I cannot spot error in

> /var/log/messages

**26 oct** : I tried with another command :

> Host $HOSTNAME

not working. With

> snmpwalk  -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890

I found this error

> iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.3.3.1.1.6.115.101.114.105.97.108 = STRING:
>   "Host \$HOSTNAME not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)"

Can I use bash variables and stdout rediretion ?
Which is the right syntax for the extensions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is a snmp' extensions newbie question.

To use variables and stdin stdout redirection, you have to prepend the command with the interpreter, like this :

> extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.2 purpose "/bin/cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_name"

Answer (score 0):

Observium supports only `distro` extend oid node, nor others.

Your extend of SNMP agent works as expected and you can check it by manually walking on `purpose` oid node.

Observium Poller can be extended to poll additional values, for example, see how "distro" node is used in `./includes/polling/os/unix.inc.php`

Comment: Fedor,  thank for your comment, but this is a SNMP config problem. I don't understand how to use bash variables in to the commands.